# Need to have 2 sticky buttons - Signup and chat

Tags: buttons, chat, signup

I have a client requirement to have 2 sticky buttons on the home page. One is for signup and the other is for the Chatbot. I need suggestions on which placement would be better with least impact on chatbot discovery and signup conversion.

Solutions I have in mind -

1. Have a sticky sign up button on the left corner and chat sticky
   button on the right corner.
2. Have the signup button in the nav bar and chat button on the right
       corner.
3. Combine the signup and chat button in a single sticky unit.
4. Move the signup in the page layout and have it at as a banner in
   between article sections(like an ad section - we don't have ads on
   the website)

Which one would you vote for? or better solutions?

Comment: Which one do you think is the best option and why? Have tested any of these layouts with the future users? What is this page used for? Is it used on mobile or desktop? Do you have any mock-ups you can show us?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! We're here to help you do your work, but not here to do your work :-)  We usually need more context than "client requirement" to base design upon. Can you give more context to the question, and also add some thoughts why these should be sticky, and why you are unsure that your first (or other) proposal is not the best?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with option 2 just because that's going to be what the user's are most familiar with. If you want people to notice and take action make sure they're a color that stands out verses the rest of the design. Adding a slight animation or having them fade in will also trigger an action.

Signup/CTA buttons are typically in the top right with a menu button in the top left corner. Chat buttons are typically in the bottom right. Following the pattern of other sites use make it so that your users don't have to think about how to find something.

Comment: Agreed #2 is definitely the most standard and accepted positioning. That doesn't mean #4 isn't an option as well. There are many situations I've tried and tested where the page content lead towards an appropriate place for a signup call to action (CTA). So even though there was already a signup button in navigation a 2nd callout on the page had higher conversion rates.

Comment: Thanks guys! I also prefer the option 2.